# What is wp-admin/meta for?

Tags: directory

I noticed that I have a directory `meta/` as a sub-directory of the wp-admin folder, but there is nothing in it. What goes in here? Should I keep it?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see that in the default wordpress install files - it may have been written by a plugin. You can probably remove it.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR:

It must have been created by **WP Super Cache plugin**.

### Detailed description

I tracked down the plugin which creates `/wp-admin/meta/` directory by comparing its modification time and server access logs. The directory was created sixteen seconds after activating [WP Super Cache plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/). Around that time a wp-cron.php check was executed.

Also, `plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php` is the only file containing `meta` near `mkdir` in plugins directory.

At that point - April 28, 2015 - site was running WordPress 4.2.1 and WP Super Cache version was 1.4.3.

Comparing WP Super Cache 1.4.3 and 1.4.4 (latest at time of this writing), doesn't show any changes in code that creates meta directory.
It is hard to tell why the directory was created in `wp-admin` but I'll update my answer if I find out.